# What are the functional differences between Lubuntu and Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, command-line, lubuntu, lxde

I understand that Lubuntu utilizes LXDE over Ubuntu's Unity(Gnome?); But being new to Linux I'm not sure if that change is going to be simply cosmetic, or if there will be functional differences I need to be aware of. The Ubuntu wiki says no, but it is also seems to be a very superficial discussion. I am comfortable(ish) with the command line and I suppose my question is more directed in that direction, but any information would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_VS_Ubuntu) says:

> Both Lubuntu and Ubuntu share:
>
> ```
> Same Core System
>
> Same Repositories
> ```
>
> The differences between Lubuntu and Ubuntu are:
>
> ```
> Different DE - Lubuntu uses LXDE while Ubuntu uses Unity as the default DE.
>
> Different Default Applications
> ```
>
> Rather than that, they are the same. The DE is what makes Lubuntu a
>   lightweight OS and of course the selected applications too because we
>   make sure to use the lightest applications which are not resource
>   hungry.

The [default applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Setup#Applications) differ. For example, Lubuntu comes with Sylpheed instead of Thunderbird. But you can manually install whatever you need because the repositories are the same.

Anything you do on the command-line will likely be the same, except that some applications may not be installed by default or you may need to edit slightly. For example, Gnome's `gnome-open` command to open a file with the default application is `xdg-open` in Unity, and in Lubuntu may be something else.